# Debouncing in react is not working if I directly call the function containing logic for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, settimeout, debouncing

I was trying to implement the debounce functionality in React inside useEffect.
Although for the below code, if I call `debounceFunc` its executing only once whereas if I directly call the `debounceFunc3` its not working.

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setEvent((pre) => [...pre, 1]);
  };
  const delayFunc = () => {
    let timer;
    return function () {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello timer 1"), 2000);
    };
  };

  const delayFunc3 = useCallback(() => {
    let timer3;
    return function () {
      clearTimeout(timer3);
      timer3 = setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello timeout3"), 2000);
    };
  }, []);

  const debounce = useCallback(delayFunc(), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (event?.length > 0) {
      debounce();
      delayFunc3()();
    }
  }, [event]);
```

In console `Hello timer 1` is printed only once whereas `Hello timeout3` is printed or each event triggered/changed.

Codebox link to play around:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lamport-sbbup?file=/src/App.js:0-872

Couldn't understand what's wring with the way I am calling `debounceFunc3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're executing `delayFunc3()` multiple times:

```js
delayFunc3()();
```

The issue with this is that every time you call `delayFunc3()()` you're creating a new local `timer3` variable within your `delayFunc3` function, and then executing the returned function that now references that new local `timer3` variable.

This means that if you call `delayFunc3()();`, first a new `timer3` variable is created, and then the returned function is executed, queueing a new timeout.

If you then call `delayFunc3()();`, again, a new `timer3` variable is created (initialized to `undefined`), and then your returned function is executed. When your returned function is executed you're runnning `clearTimeout(timer3);`, which won't be clearing any timer as `timer3` here is referring to the new `timer3` variable that was initialized and is `undefined`, and not the previous `timer3` that was created in the previous function `delayFunc3()()` call.

As a result, calling `delayFunc3()();` again while your first timeout is still running won't have any effect on the first timeout as the `timer3` created by this invocation has no relation to the previous `timer3` created, and so it won't be cleared.

Unlike this, performing the following:

```js
const debounce = useCallback(delayFunc(), []);
```

executes your `delayFunc()` and creates a new local variable `timer` within the scope of `delayFunc()`. The returned function from `delayFunc()` [closes over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the `timer` variable declared within the `delayFunc()` scope. This means that whenever `debounce()` is executed, you won't be creating a new `timer` variable like you were in your first example, but instead, you will be reusing the `timer` created from the initial `delayFunc()` call. Each call to `debounce()` will reuse the same `timer` variable, and so, if `debounce()` is called again, the `clearTimeout(timer);` will clear the previously queued timer.

---

Also note that in both of your examples, you're using `useCallback()` on two different things. With `debounce`, you're calling `useCallback()` on the returned function from `delayFunc()`. This means that all future rerenders of your component will use the one function reference that was returned from the initial `delayFunc()` call when your component mounted. So `debounce` refers to the one unique function for all rerenders.

Unlike this, `delayFunc3` is using `useCallback()` not on the returned function, but rather the entire function (ie: the "parent" arrow function). This means that each rerender of your component will use the same "parent" function, but that parent function still creates a new `timer3` variable when invoked and returns a new inner function each time it is called.

Comment: Hello Nick,
Thanks for answering.

I still couldn't understand why new instance of that function is created each time I call it.
With the help of useCallBack hook I can return the same instance or memoized value of that function, hence same variable should be referenced by clearTimeout.

Is this wrong?

Comment: @KunwarVirajSuryavanshi That's right, but with `delayFunc3`, you're using `useCallback()` on your entire function and not the returned function, so `delayFunc3` is a reference to the entire function, which when called, creates a new `timer3` local variable each time it is called. `debounce` is slightly different to `delayFunc3` in that it uses `useCallback` not on the entire function, but on the returned function, because you're calling the `delayFunc()` here which returns the inner function `useCallback(delayFunc(), []);`. So only the first function returned from `delayFunc()` is used

Comment: @KunwarVirajSuryavanshi I've updated my answer a little to try and explain how `useCallback()` is being used and why it's behaving differently for both examples.